# Injected class in helper in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, helper

I have my helper where I want to implement my override logger.
The logger work perfect outside the helper but I can't make it work inside the helper:

```
namespace Acme\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

protected $_logger;

public function __construct(
     \Acme\Module\Logger\Logger $logger
) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}

public function setLogger($message, $context = info) {
    $this->_logger->info("y pues anda daleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
}
```

But looks like the whay i am injecting the logger class it is not the correct way to do it. I just get a 500 error so I think it is a problem in the way i am injecting the class into the helper.

=====================================================================

## Edited

I manage to avoid the injection error adding a context in the construct but now my class is not overriding the logger as it should:

```
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

protected $httpHeader;
protected $mobileAgent;

public function __construct(
    \Acme\Module\Logger\Logger $logger, 
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
   public function setLogger($message, $context = false) {
    $this->_logger->info("y pues anda ooooooooooo");
}
```

I also found out that the context can get the folowing methods in the helper:

```
$context->getRequest(); // return \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
$context->getUrlBuilder(); // return \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
$context->getScopeConfig(); // return \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
$context->getLogger(); // return \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
$context->getEventManager(); // return \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
$context->getModuleManager(); // return \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
$context->getCacheConfig(); // return \Magento\Framework\Cache\ConfigInterface
$context->getHttpHeader(); // return \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header
$context->getRemoteAddress(); // return \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress
$context->getUrlEncoder(); // return \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface
$context->getUrlDecoder(); // return \Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface
```

Comment: What do you have in error logs?

Comment: No errors.  if i make a comment on the construct all work fine but instead of create a new log file using my own class it is  adding the text in the default system.log.  I know that my log class work fine in another class like the controller for example.  I am missing something in the injection of the class but I don't know what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class injection in the Helper works as any other class the only thing to have in mind it is the context that needs to be related to the helper:

For example:

```
namespace Acme\Mymodule\Helper;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

protected $logger;

public function __construct(
LoggerInterface $logger, \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

The context will bring this intresting methods:

```
$context->getRequest(); // return \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
$context->getUrlBuilder(); // return \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
$context->getScopeConfig(); // return \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
$context->getLogger(); // return \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
$context->getEventManager(); // return \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
$context->getModuleManager(); // return \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
$context->getCacheConfig(); // return \Magento\Framework\Cache\ConfigInterface
$context->getHttpHeader(); // return \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header
$context->getRemoteAddress(); // return \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress
$context->getUrlEncoder(); // return \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface
$context->getUrlDecoder(); // return \Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of this line:

```
public function setLogger($message, $context = info)
```

where info is constant. Change it to

```
public function setLogger($message, $context)
```

Comment: The info constant it is there but the error happen anyway if i just take all the parameters away.  Or even if i take the constructor and let the function use the _logger directly from the magento monolog\Logger